# String Tokenization with " ", breaking at "."

Tags: c++, string, parsing, input, substring

Encountering an issue where I am trying to tokenize a string that came from a getline from console. It's breaking at " " as well as "." when I only want it to break at " ".

Here is the method that I've created for this problem:

```
queue<string> getStringList(string list, string delimiter) {
    queue<string> values;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = list.find(delimiter) != string::npos))
    {
        token = list.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        values.push(token);
        list.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    std::cout << list << endl;
    return values;
}
```

Sample Input:

> cid arrival_time dir_original dir_target
>
> 0 1.1 ^ ^
>
> 1 2.0 ^ ^
>
> 2 3.3 ^ <
>
> 3 3.5 v v
>
> 4 4.2 v >
>
> 5 4.4 ^ ^
>
> 6 5.7 > ^
>
> 7 5.9 < ^

[image]

This how the data is breaking up from the line previous.

Comment: Please edit your post with sample code, [mcve], that calls `getStringList`.  Need to know what value you are passing for the delimiter.

Comment: Not sure that matters (I mean the delimiter value, obviously an MRE is desirable), @Thomas, that variant of `string::find` only matches a complete string, not a choice of characters. There shouldn't be any way for it to match both `<space>` and `.`, should it?

Comment: Ashley, I'm curious as to why it didn't act on your first line of input. Or do you ignore that (since it seems to be a header line)?

Comment: @paxdiablo have it skipping the first line in another part of the program because I knew it'd be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((pos = list.find(delimiter) != string::npos))
```

You have the parentheses in the wrong place, meaning what you have is the equivalent of:

```
while ((pos = (list.find(delimiter) != string::npos) ))
//            (compare first-----------------------)
//     (then assign----------------------------------)
```

In terms of operator precedence, assignment is *way* down the list, long after comparisons.

So `pos` will always be either zero (if you don't find the space) or one (if you do find it). It will *never* be equal to the position of that space in the string, except for the pathological case where the space is the second character.

That's why everything works for your one-character fields, but not for the three-character `1.1` field. It correctly *finds* the space at position 3 but, because `pos` has been set to one, it uses `substr` in a way that deletes the `.`.

That line *should* be:

```
while ((pos = list.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
//     (assign first--------------)
//     (then compare-------------------------------)
```

---

With a full program and the fix mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

queue<string> getStringList(string list, string delimiter) {
    queue<string> values;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = list.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
        token = list.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        values.push(token);
        list.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    values.push(list);
    std::cout << list << endl;
    return values;
}

int main () {
    string x = "0 1.1 ^ ^";
    string delim = " ";

    auto y = getStringList(x, delim);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the output is now correct:

```
0
1.1
^
^
```

---

And, as per a comment from Remy Lebeau, you *print* the final element but do not add it to the list. Hence I've added the line that appends that last token to the list of tokens.

One other thing to watch out for. While this works well with single-space separators, multi-space ones may cause issues. If that becomes an issue, you may need a more "bullet-proof" tokenising routine.

Comment: It should also be noted that altough `getStringList()` *prints out* all of the tokens, it does not *push* the last token into `values`. When `find()` return `npos`, a final `values.push(list)` is needed if `list` is not empty. If `delimiter` can be changed to a `char` instead then I would suggest putting `list` into a `std::istringstream` and then use `while (std::getline(iss, token, delimiter))` instead, then no tokens are missed.